# exception thrown from a Win32 call on XP

Tags: c++, winapi, exception

All,

I have an XP SP3 machine that is crashing using my software only when it is run from home, wirelessly connected but no domain controller or anything.

I get the following dump

```
Call stack below ---
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
00 0337ddc8 77e9f942 000006ba 00000001 00000000 kernel32!RaiseException+0x52
01 0337dde0 77e9fc30 000006ba 0337e1f4 0337e1d8 RPCRT4!RpcRaiseException+0x34
02 0337ddf0 77ef560b 0337de3c 0000004c 00217d40 RPCRT4!RpcRaiseException+0x322
03 0337e1d8 77de1ee8 77ddf4b0 77de14e4 0337e1f4 RPCRT4!NdrClientCall2+0x13b
04 0337e1ec 77de1e6a 00209878 0337e260 00000800 ADVAPI32!LsaOpenPolicy+0xc1
05 0337e240 77de5be7 0337e28c 0337e260 00000800 ADVAPI32!LsaOpenPolicy+0x43
06 0337e2a8 77de5b7a 015246d0 0337e930 0337e3f0 ADVAPI32!LookupAccountNameW+0x8e
07 0337e2d0 10006903 015246d0 0337e930 0337e3f0 ADVAPI32!LookupAccountNameW+0x21
```

The code that I suspect is

```
char aTmp[MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwSize=sizeof(aTmp);
SID_NAME_USE aTmp2;
unsigned short usDmn[MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwDmn=sizeof(usDmn);

wchar_t* pDomain;
if (!rDomain.empty())
    pDomain=(wchar_t*)rDomain.c_str();
else
    pDomain=NULL;

if (!LookupAccountNameW(pDomain, (wchar_t*)rUser.c_str(), (PSID)aTmp,
                        &dwSize,
                        (LPWSTR)usDmn,
                        &dwDmn,
                        &aTmp2))
    //Error
    return aInfo;
```

user and domain are string vars that are passed in...

Anything obvious I am missing? What exception Is being thrown?`enter code here`

Comment: Why are you  using a char array for param 3 instead of a SID struct?  In your use case is pDomain NULL or not?   Also, do you  need the SID or SID_NAME_USE?  You can pass in NULLs if you don't.

Comment: From MSDN:

Sid [out, optional]
A pointer to a buffer that receives the SID structure that corresponds to the account name pointed to by the lpAccountName parameter. If this parameter is NULL, cbSid must be zero.

Comment: Repost this code will all the casts removed.

Comment: I know what that parameter does; I don't know why you're not allocating a SID struct and passing it's address in, or sending in NULL if you don't need it.  You're sending in a char array which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Other observations aside, dwDmn looks suspect.  You are passing the size in bytes whereas the function expects size in characters.

Answer (score 2):

Everywhere you cast is probably an error. You've not shown us all the definitions but the very fact that you are casting suggests something is wrong. You appear to be passing ANSI parameters to a Unicode function.

Why are you using unsigned
short instead of a wide char?

Also your SID looks all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `rUser` is `string` and not `wstring`, assuming you needed to add the `(wchar_t*)` cast to the call to `.c_str()` to make the compiler not complain.

Similarly, `rDomain` may also be of the 8-bit `string` type instead of the 16-bit `wstring` type.

Comment: I am sorry the domain and user are wstring and NOT string

Comment: @reza: Then why are you casting the result of rUser.c_str()?

Comment: I am converting wstring to wchar_t*

Comment: @reza: Casting is not converting.  Are you sure it's doing what you think it is?